# Example of Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I am reading [Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV5fmn9Y3OAhVMtJQKHbo_DMAQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.duke.edu%2F~rtd%2FPTE%2FPTE4_1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGy3lo2UEcIsyhNWe0luCMmQ66yRA&sig2=7JFkwjqvLEVo2y6ckrblEw), and trying to understand its context about Markov Chains. It is not hard to understand the theorem and proofs but when it comes to concrete examples, I have a hard time calculate the answer....

Theorem 6.3.1 states that: Let $Y:\Omega_0 \rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ be bounded and measurable.
$$
E_\mu(Y\circ\theta_n\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=E_{X_n}Y$$

Now, I am trying to give an example and try to figure out what the theorem really means.

Suppose that we are given a two states markov chain with transition matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 1/2 & 1/2\\
\end {pmatrix}
$$

And the initial distribution $(1,0)$. How can I calculate $E_{X_2}Y$?
Also, how to verify the theorem if $Y=\omega_1+2\omega_2$ and $n=2$?

The term $E_{X_2}Y$, as what I have understood, is the expectation of Y given the initial distribution $X_2$. However, I have no idea the exact calculation is.

Thank you!

Comment: It would help to add the relevant context, namely what $\theta_n$ is.